# Is 'would' used instead of 'was' to mean probability in past time?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-usage, sentence-choice

- I knew that class test would be held at 11:00 AM.
- I knew that there was class test at 11:00 AM.

What are the differences between them? Do they mean same meaning?

Comment: Using "was" does not indicate probability. BTW, "*the/a* class test".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Firstly - class test requires an *article*: the *definite article*, "the"; or the *indefinite article*, "a".)

> I knew that *the* class test would be held at 11:00 AM.

This is in essence a statement of what you believed in the past.  In the past, you believed that, at a moment which was then in the future but which is now in the past, a class test was going to be held.

> I knew that there was [going to be] *a* class test at 11:00 AM.

Back in the past I was certain **either** that a class test was happening at that same time, **or** that a class test had already happened at an even earlier moment in time

> I knew that there would be *a* class test at 11:00 AM.

I knew, back in the past, that there was going to be a class test in my then future, which is now also the past.

[The British Council's web site (link)](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/will-or-would) says

> ...
>   would is the past tense form of will. Because it is a past tense it is used:
>
> to talk about the past.
>   to talk about hypotheses – things that are imagined rather than true.
>   for politeness.